# Nohup is not working inside a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute commands on multiple linux remote server.
I have written a shell script but it is not able to execute remote command.
The script is correctly reading username and ip from a config file but not able to execute remote command.
**nohup command is not passing value of ${interval}, ${delay} and $file.csv.**

```
interval==${1:-1}
delay=${2:-1800}
b=Server-
c=1
d=-
a=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)
INDEX=0
while read NAMES[${INDEX}] IP[${INDEX}]
do
  ((INDEX=$INDEX+1))
done < config

for (( i=0,j=i+1; i<${INDEX}; i++,j++ ))
do
echo "Server $j Username : "${NAMES[i]}
echo "Server $j IP : "${IP[i]}
file=$b$c$d$a
echo "Server $j file name : "$file
nohup ssh ${NAMES[i]}@${IP[i]} 'vmstat -n ${interval} ${delay} > $file.csv' >& /dev/null &
let c++
done
```

In config file,entries are like "username ip"  :

```
ajX 11.22.33.44
mnc 55.66.77.88
```

I don't get any error while executing my script. Output of Script is :

```
Server 1 Username : ajX
Server 1 IP : 11.22.33.44
Server 1 file name : Server-1-2013-09-18-07-39
Server 2 Username : mnc
Server 2 IP : 55.66.77.88
Server 2 file name : Server-2-2013-09-18-07-39
```

But on remote servers, commands are not executed but if I execute it individually

```
nohup ssh ajx@11.22.33.44 'vmstat -n 1 30 > vmfile.csv' >& /dev/null &
```

it works fine. Does nohup doesn't work inside for loop or is there some other way to do the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try saying `nohup ssh -l ${NAMES[i]} ${IP[i]} ...`

Comment: Not working with "-l"

Comment: @ajay Try not redirecting it to /dev/null first and see if there are some helpful messages you can get: `nohup ssh ajx@11.22.33.44 "vmstat -n 1 30 > vmfile.csv" &`. Make sure you use doulbequotes as well. Perhaps try it without `nohup` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
nohup ssh ${NAMES[i]}@${IP[i]} 'vmstat -n ${interval} ${delay} > $file.csv'
```

to

```
nohup ssh ${NAMES[i]}@${IP[i]} "vmstat -n ${interval} ${delay} > $file.csv"
```

Because you use apostrohpies, the ${interval} and ${delay} arguments are not resolved on the client, and the server is simply complaining (sending error to stderr, which you do not catch.)

There is also an error you call.
You have:

```
nohup ssh ${NAMES[i]}@${IP[i]} 'vmstat -n ${interval} ${delay} > $file.csv' >& /dev/null &
```

It should be

```
nohup ssh ${NAMES[i]}@${IP[i]} "vmstat -n ${interval} ${delay} > $file.csv" > /dev/null &
```

Comment: You are correct that ${interval} and ${delay} are not resolved on the client. As if I execute any other command without passing arguments it works fine. 
But you solution of replacing '' with "" doesn't worked.

Comment: I didn't get it `nohup ssh ${NAMES[i]}@${IP[i]} "vmstat -n ${interval} ${delay} > $file.csv' > /dev/null &` where does " will close?

Comment: @ajay: Sorry. I have copied your text, and modified one apostrophy only. I have correcthed command line.

Comment: It is executing vmstat command and creating file on remote server but of 0 Kb i.e arguments are still not passing with command.